# Displaying N - parent N - Child menu Django

Tags: mysql, html, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

Here i stucked up with a piece of code

let me explain you what i want
 to display my items like this

```
Chocolate
    Hot chocolate
    White Chocolate
        Salted caramel hot chocolate
    Peppermint hot chocolate
Espresso Beverage
    caffe Americano
    caffe latte
       caffe Moche
    Cappuccino
Frappuccino
    a
       b
          c
              d
```

Here i am using Django view and template for displaying

In my Mysql table i have inserted all these records with
four column   1.id    2.name   3.slug    4.parent

In the display above

```
 eg  Chocolate  is with id one  and parent 0
       Hot chocolate  is with id 2 and parent 1
       White Chocolate  is with id 3 and parent 1
       Salted caramel hot chocolate is with id 4 and parent 3
       Espresso Beverage  is with id 6 and parent 0
```

hope you understood

my html code

```
 {% for cat in user %}
  {% if cat.parent = 0%}
  <ul id="listMenu" style="list-style-type:none; margin-left:-50">  

      <li class="listparent"><p style="font-size:15px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;color: black;">{{cat.name}}<br></a></p></li>
     {% for cat1 in user %}
    {% if cat1.parent = cat.id%}
     <ul class="menuitems" style="list-style-type:none;">  

    <li class="listchild"> <p class="Tier1" style="font-size:15px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;color: black;" >{{cat1.name}}<br></a></p></li>

      </ul>

     {%endif%}
       {% endfor %} 
       </ul>
      {%endif%}
       {% endfor %}
```

and my view

```
error = 50
@login_required 
def categories(request):
     context = RequestContext(request)
     user = Categories.objects.all()
     if request.method == 'POST':
           catform = CategoryForm(data=request.POST)
           post_values = request.POST.copy() 
           post_values['userid'] = request.user.id
           post_values['createdby'] = request.user.id
           post_values['modifiedby'] = request.user.id
           catform = CategoryForm(post_values)        
           if catform.is_valid():
                 is_valid = True 
             profile = catform.save(commit=False)
                 profile.save()
                 registered = True
                 messages.add_message(request, error, 'Category Added.')  
           else:
                 messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Invalid input check your slug or order.')
     else:
         catform = CategoryForm()
     paginator = Paginator(user, 20)     
     try: page = int(request.GET.get("page", '1'))
     except ValueError: page = 1

     try:
         user = paginator.page(page)
     except (InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
         user = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
     return render_to_response('myapp/categories.html',{'catform':catform,'user':user},context)
```

Please suggest me some logic to get my required output

with the above code i could achieve 1 parent 1 child
not n parent n child

Thanks in Advance  :_)

Comment: So no one having enough knowledge to help me here huh??

Comment: i got the answer own,thnx for your help.